# Perform column search on next table if record not found in previous table in db2 sql query

Tags: sql, db2

I have three tables with same columns

```
table 1
    col1 col2 col3 col4

table 2
    col1 col2 col3 col4

table 3
    col1 col2 col3 col4
```

I have to perform a search if record is not found on **table1** then only go to search in **table2** and if not found in **table2** then go to **table3**. But if record found in any of these table then perform some calculation on col4 and return col4 without execution further. I am using DB2 but not able to find
the exact solution . How can i achieve this ?.

Comment: Without seeing any code: something like 3x `LEFT JOIN`s, second and third ones should check in the join condition for result from previous joins

Comment: @Charlieface but all data is different in tables

Comment: *But if record found in any of these table then perform some calculation on col4 ...* this part I don't understand

Comment: That is what a `LEFT JOIN` is for. Do you know how write SQL?

Comment: @Charlieface yes i have been working on sql and mysql but db2 is somehow different so i was not sure about joins approach so i did this "  if exists (Select 1 from table1 where cloumnX = 'xyz')
        Select * from table1 where cloumnX = 'xyz' " . but it says [SQL0199] Keyword IF not expected. Valid tokens: . But i do want to understand the trick from left join you were referring to . That would be of great help .

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos What i meant from that statement is , If record is found in table1 then get col4 and perform some expression which is fine but logic of skipping to other table if record is not found is what i am looking for mainly .

Comment: Joins are very standardized across SQL Server, MySQL and DB2. Are you saying: we have no driving rows at all to left join from? I.e. your starting query is that select? And we only have ever one row?

Comment: Your query returns just one row every time?

Comment: @Charlieface yes there will be no row matching , the data is completely different , Its just that we have divided data in three tables which will be of different use for further . so we can not combine them .

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos yes one match is needed only .

Comment: DB2 needs `THEN` following an `IF`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to keep this as one query, you can use `UNION ALL` to get the correct table:

```sql
SELECT col4, 1 as SortCol
    FROM Table1
    WHERE col1 = 'whatever'
UNION ALL
SELECT col4, 2 as SortCol
    FROM Table2
    WHERE col1 = 'whatever'
UNION ALL
SELECT col4, 3 as SortCol
    FROM Table3
    WHERE col1 = 'whatever'

ORDER BY SortCol
FETCH 1 ROW ONLY;
```

---

*EDIT*
Another method is possible. I must say, I'm unsure coming from SQL Server the exact syntax, but it would be something like this:

```
SELECT COALESCE(t1.col4, t2.col4, t3.col4)

FROM (VALUES (@col1, @col2) ) v(col1, col2)
LEFT JOIN Table1 t1 ON t1.col1 = v.col1 AND t1.col2 = v.col2
LEFT JOIN Table2 t2 ON t2.col1 = v.col1 AND t2.col2 = v.col2
    AND t1.col4 IS NULL
LEFT JOIN Table3 t3 ON t3.col1 = v.col1 AND t3.col2 = v.col2
    AND t1.col4 IS NULL AND t2.col4 IS NULL;
```

The idea being to use the `VALUES` clause (or a `SELECT` with no `FROM`) as a driving row.

Comment: Suppose if record is found on 1st one then it should not go to second statement but Union All eventually goes to check record again in second table . Isn't it ? correct me if i am wrong .

Comment: Not with a `ORDER BY... FETCH 1` it won't

Comment: Thank you for prompt response . I would also like to know the second way that is left join the trick you were referring to , assuming if records are matching . Just curious about the logic you will implement there .

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
select col1 col2 col3 col4
from (
   select col1 col2 col3 col4, 1 as lvl
   from table_1
   where some_condition  

   union all

   select col1 col2 col3 col4, 2 as lvl
   from table_2
   where some_condition

   union all

   select col1 col2 col3 col4, 3 as lvl
   from table_3
   where some_condition) as t
order by lvl
limit 1
```

Comment: Suppose if record is found on 1st one then it should not go to second statement but Union All eventually goes to check record again in second table . Isn't it ? correct me if i am wrong .

Comment: Thank you for the prompt response you have also solved my problem . I appreciate your help . Thank you sir .

Answer (score 0):

Similar to what the other posters suggest, you could use code like this if you explicitly want to follow your "if then" logic

```
CREATE TABLE TABLE_1(C1 INT, C2 INT, C3 INT, C4 INT)

CREATE TABLE TABLE_2(C1 INT, C2 INT, C3 INT, C4 INT)

CREATE TABLE TABLE_3(C1 INT, C2 INT, C3 INT, C4 INT)

WITH
  C4(C1, C2, C3, C4) AS (VALUES (1,2,3,4))
, T1 AS ( SELECT '1' AS LVL, * FROM TABLE_1 JOIN C4 USING (C1, C2, C3, C4) )
, T2 AS ( SELECT '2' AS LVL, * FROM TABLE_2 JOIN C4 USING (C1, C2, C3, C4) WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM T1))
, T3 AS ( SELECT '3' AS LVL, * FROM TABLE_3 JOIN C4 USING (C1, C2, C3, C4) WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM T2))
, T4 AS ( SELECT '4' AS LVL, * FROM C4                                     WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM T3))
SELECT * FROM T1 UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM T2 UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM T3 UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM T4
```